# How to manipulate files and directories in WebBrowser in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, data-manipulation

I want to create a simple file manager with C# and I tried to do it using Web Browser.

Now, I suppose to delete, copy, rename, copy, cut and paste files and directories with Web Browser.

How? The user should select each file or directory, then click on "Copy" button -which I specified in form- and then go to destination then click on "Paste" button. user should do other operations like that.

I had some problems:

1. How can I realize source path, when user select a file or directory in Web Browser?
2. Can I personalize right click menu and then do all I had before, in new menu? I mean close explorer right click and implement my new personalized menu.

Comment: Is it WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @opewix It's WinForms